# Why i can't connect to gorilla websocket server from front page?

Tags: vue.js, go, websocket, gorilla

backend code:

```
func WsHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    }
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(c.Writer, c.Request, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    client := wsserver.Client{
        Id:         wsserver.AutoId(),
        Connection: conn,
        IsConnect:  true,
        MessageCh:  make(chan wsserver.WsMessage),
    }
    global.GD_WS.AddClient(client)
    // defer conn.Close()
    fmt.Println("New Client is connected, total: ", len(global.GD_WS.Clients))
    go handleReciveMsg(client)
    go global.GD_WS.PublishNew(client)

}
```

//router:

```
func initWebsocketRouter(Router *gin.RouterGroup) {
    Router.GET("ws",apis.WsHandler)
}
```

the finally router path is:
**"/system/ws**"

**//front page code:**

```
const wsInit =async()=>{
    const ws = window.WebSocket ? new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:6666/system/ws') : null
    ws.onopen = function () {
        console.log('success!')
        ws.send('startting...')
      }
      ws.onclose = function () {
        console.log('close')
      }
      ws.onerror = function () {
        console.log('error')
      }
      ws.onmessage = function (e) {
        console.log(e.data)
      }
    //      
}
wsInit()
```

**then i got error:**
"WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:6666/system/ws' failed: " with no reason

but in a single nodejs file it works fine,nodejs file code blew:

```
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;

var client = new WebSocketClient();

client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
});

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function() {
        console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
    });
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log("Received: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
        }
    });
    connection.send('{"action":"subscribe","topic":"coin"}')
    connection.send('{"action":"subscribe","topic":"gas"}')
});

client.connect('ws://localhost:6666/system/ws');
```

why this happen?

hope someone can help,it alrea confused me two days

Comment: thanks mate,it's finally solved